# Excel row and column selection with merged cells in the way

Tags: excel, selection, excel-2016

I'll keep it short :

something changed recently with the user experience in excel 2016. when clicking the row or column headers and if there is a merged cell in the way the selection extends which am sure wasn't the case a while ago !!

**all what am trying to do is to add a single row or column in a table with merged cells**

Comment: It does not do that for me. Which build of Excel are you using? File, Account shows that information. NB: Merging cells is a PITA and not recommended for obvious reasons like selecting, filtering etc.

Comment: Version 1805 Build 9330.2124 ... true but also good for layout management

Comment: What is your Version and Build ?